# how to use closure for passing multiple argument in closure in groovy

Tags: groovy, closures

below is my groovy code I want to pass multiple arguments in closure in groovy

```
package com.test.demo

def str = {'Yash' , 'deep'}
def merged = { println "$str world"}

merged.call()
```

this code is giving me an error please anyone give me a solution how can I pass multiple arguments in closure  in groovy

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What error are you getting? If you need to have parameters in closures, you declare them: `{param1, param2 -> ...code here...}`

Comment: WHAT error? You are capturing `str` here already - passing would usually mean, you pass it via `call`.  Do you really want to print `[Yash, deep] world` here?

Comment: @cfrick yes i want to print [Yash,deep] world

Comment: The code you provide works as is in the groovy web console. What error are you seeing?

Comment: @tim_yates I have edited the question because of the syntax error in the example. But I guess OP really wants a closure and therefor reverted the edit.

Answer (score -1):

There are two problems with your original code:

`{ 'Yash' , 'deep' }` does not imply returning an array, but this will
give you an error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
/tmp/x.groovy: 2: Unexpected input: ',' @ line 2, column 19.
   def str = {'Yash' , 'deep'}
```

So you have to rewrite that closure to:

```
{['Yash' , 'deep']}
```

(note the `[]`)

Next, if you print the closure like this, you would get the reference
printed - so you need to call it.

```
def merged = { println "${it()} world"}
def str = {['Yash' , 'deep']}
merged(str)
```